# Shopware 6: The "https://packages.shopware.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 500 ) SOLVED

Tags: shopware, shopware6

When I run the following command
`composer search store.shopware.com/*` I'm getting the following Error:

> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> The "https://packages.shopware.com/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 500 )

Can someone tell me, how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

- Is your token valid?
- After you copied the token from the Shopware Account modal, you have to press save. Only when pressing the button, the copied token will be active

Comment: I checked my token. It was invalid so I fixed it. Now everything is working. 

Thank you for your help.

Comment: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-22280